# C# and File.WriteAllText error

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I am building a simple C# application that has to write the user input in a file.

My first problem is that i want the user to be able to set the path of the settings file, but i want the program to be able to read the settings file on the following starts.

My second problem is that if i use something like :

```
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\settings.settings", message);
```

i get the following error :

```
    System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 
    'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. at 
    System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& 
    stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
    Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions 
    options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
    FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)

    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
    FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)

     at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
    at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
    at IMDBGrabber.frmSettings.writeToFile(String p)
    The action that failed was: Demand

    The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission

    The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Check the permission of the target folder per the user running the application. Use a try catch to trap the SecurityException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project => properties and check the Security tab. Uncheck "Enable ClickOnce security settings" and try again.
If the problem persists uncheck the only option from Signing tab as well.

Comment: Only for console app?

Answer (score 6):

It is surprising, but not all users have access to `"C:\Users\Public"`.

Try putting your file in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\settings.settings";`

All users should have access to write there.

Also consider using an app-specific subfolder as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run my app as an administrator in order to write to protected folders in c:.  For example if debugging your app in visual studio make sure to right click on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" and choose "Run As Administrator".  Then open your solution from there.  My app  was trying to write to the root of c:\

Answer (score 0):

Is your C:\Users\Public folder writable ? If it isn't, make sure it is, because the exception trace is telling you that there is a SecurityException (related to security problems, as you might have guessed), and that the previous exception was related to file IO. So it's most likely that your app. doesn't (or the user running it) doesn't have write permissions on that folder.

Comment: This is a Security exception, not an IO exception. It has nothing to do with whether the folder is writable.

Comment: How can i check if the user can write ? Is there any other way to hold some data than writing it to a file ?

Comment: I must apologize. My eyes failed me when I saw the phrase : The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.. and furthermore, extrapolating that the exception that was thrown was related to file IO is really a blunder. I am truly sorry.

Comment: Additionally, making the link between the security and file I/O is another blunder. Sorry, so sorry.